# PHP Codeigniter Active Records Ignore single quote

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi I have following string to insert into database

```
$data = array('url' => http://www.amazon.co.uk/hedge-trimmers/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i:aps,k:'hedge trimmers);
```

I tired to insert that but I am getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hedge trimmers''' at line 1

SELECT * FROM seo_websites WHERE website = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/hedge-trimmers/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i:aps,k:'hedge trimmers''
```

I think it is do with single quotes. Please I would really appreciate if someone can help me.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your query using Active Record

```
 $url="http://www.amazon.co.uk/hedge-trimmers/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i:aps,k:'hedge trimmers'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('seo_websites');
    $this->db->where('website',$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('url' => addslashes("http://www.amazon.co.uk/hedge-trimmers/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i:aps,k:'hedge trimmers"));
```